# How do I make an AND gate from transistors?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic

I'm trying to make an AND gate from two transistors in series as described here (http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Electronic/trangate.html), so I made a simple circuit with push buttons to light an LED when AND is true (the third transistor is just to get from logic level signals to a current that can actually power something). However if I only press the 2nd button, it also lights up.

As I understand this is because the part of the transistor between base and emitter works as a diode pointing toward the emitter, but then you get current even when the collector is disconnected completely, and so the AND gate as described in the link doesn't work! How do you solve this issue? What is the least number of transistors needed to make a working AND gate?

NOTE: The buttons and LED are just to test whether the AND gate functions correctly. (If the purpose were to light up the LED when both buttons are pressed, I could simply replace the transistors with the buttons!) When I get this working it will be integrated into a larger chain of logic gates, or the input signals may come from some other device.

[image]

Comment: @winny How does it look like they are upside down? The LED is pointing toward the negative side of the battery.

Comment: You can make an nand gate with a single bipolar transistor. You can make an and with 2. If you don't care about outputs being compatible with inputs, you can make an and gate with two diodes and a resistor and no transistors.

Comment: @winny That would effectively imply you can't have any other components on the same vertical line as the battery, correct?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Do you mind showing how?

Comment: @QwertYuiop One of the key questions I have, that underlies your question, is whether or not you want a single-use AND gate that only works as a demonstration but cannot be combined with other such gates, more generally. Or if you want a design that can be used as a general purpose logic gate that can be combined in a variety of interesting ways with other gates. Which is it? Also, power is often a consideration when many gates will be combined. If you want a general purpose gate then is power per gate also a concern for you, too?

Comment: I would be glad to show you, but at the moment I only have a phone, so I can't use CircuitLab to give you schematics. If no-one has shown you by tomorrow US time, I will add an answer.

Comment: @periblepsis Yes I'm looking for a general purpose gate that can be integrated with other gates. Power should be low by keeping the currents low, right? Then just use another transistor at the end to amplify for the actuator you want to drive.

Comment: @QwertYuiop Keeping the current low is good for low power. But it is difficult without using more transistors. A single BJT gate (NOR, for example) will use resistors and will dissipate more power than if a few BJTs are added, instead. So more transistors will mean lower power consumption. But more space and wiring. Everything in engineering is about finding acceptable compromises of various goals. Only by quantifying how each are weighed can some "preferred optimum" be found. Yes, transducer circuits are needed to generate inputs and to consume the logic outputs and transfer them into action.

Comment: @periblepsis For now since I'm just experimenting and there are limits to what fits on my breadboard, I'll go for less components unless the power consumption is really ridiculous. I can consider lower power optimizations later if I make something that I want to run constantly for longer periods.

Comment: @QwertYuiop There is [this link from EESE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/281320/330261) that probably covers the basics, then.

Comment: Replace R1 with 68kOhm and the base current through Q2 alone will not be enough to make Q3 conduct anything.

Comment: @QwertYuiop [Here's an external article that was published in 1971](https://www.rfcafe.com/references/popular-electronics/equivalency-rtl-circuits-popular-electronics-february-1971.htm) that provides another detailed view on RTL from that day and time.

Comment: Much better! Thank you.

Comment: Simon Fitch has posted an answer showing how to build an and gate with diodes and a resistor. Add an inverter made from a single transistor and resistor, and you get an nand gate, which Simon Fitch also shows. Add a second inverter, and you have an and gate again, although this time, with outputs compatible with the inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: Before you read on, the ideas I present here are not optimal. There are probably common-base solutions that better fit the requirement for AND behaviour, and you could probably pare down a classic TTL design from inside a 74 series logic IC for better results.

If you are going to chain several such "modules" together, then you require voltage gain. As you have it, all your transistors are connected "common collector", otherwise known as "emitter follower". As the name suggests, emitter potential follows the base, with a voltage gain of 1, and a base-emitter-junction-voltage of \$V_{BE}=0.6V\$ lower.

See [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/661824/292884) for information about followers. It references source followers, using MOSFETs, but the principle is the same for BJTs.

In your circuit, output potential at the collector of Q3 can never be higher than \$5V - 2\times V_{BE} = 3.8V\$, because you incur a loss of \$V_{BE}\$ at Q2's emitter, and another \$V_{BE}\$ at Q3's emitter. Imagine such losses accumulating with each cascaded logic stage. After two or three stages, there's nothing left.

Ideally you would want the output of any such logic gate to be a clear, emphatic +5V or 0V, so you will probably require voltage gain greater than 1, to bring the signal back to that maximum potential swing. Using a single transistor to achieve this would necessitate one of the following *common emitter* (as opposed to common collector, or emitter follower) configurations:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJGjhN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the left we use an NPN device, on the right is PNP. Note that I haven't included base resistors, to limit base current, because whether you need them depends on the source of signal driving the bases. As you should be aware, this configuration inverts. A high base potential will cause a low output (collector) potential, and vice versa.

Your choice of NPN or PNP here depends on what your output is intended to drive (whether the following stage or module is sinking or sourcing current), and also (to some extent) whether the previous stage is a source or sink of current.

I am not suggesting that you *must* use these configurations, I want simply to point out that at some point in the chain, you will probably have to recover any "lost" signal amplitude, with some voltage gain *above* 1, and this is a way to do that. Just be aware of the inversion that also occurs.

You are correct in your assessment that the base-emitter junction of Q2 is acting like a diode, causing a high potential at its base to raise emitter potential, in spite of whatever Q1 is trying to do. Q1 is powerless to prevent this.

MOSFETs do not suffer this problem, since their gates are completely isolated from drain and source; no such "diode" junction is present between gate and source to cause this behaviour. That's why it's OK to use MOSFETs in this configuration, but *not* BJTs. If you swap Q1 and Q2 for MOSFETs, then your problem goes away, although you'll need extra resistors to set explicitly gate potential while the switches are open, and you'll have to contend with a much larger voltage drop of \$V_{GS(TH)}\$. Such "source follower" arrangements  would work better with a larger supply, say +12V instead of +5V.

I'll assume from here on that you wish to stick with bipolar junction transistors. Actually, let's start with using just diodes. Here are a couple of interesting setups called "Diode-OR" (left) and "Diode-AND" (right):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLexZV.png)</sup>

On the left, *any* high input at A, B or C will forward bias the corresponding diode, causing it to conduct, and "pulling" up the potential at F. This is the behaviour you expect from an OR gate.

On the right, the output is high (pulled up by R2), unless *any* of the inputs A, B or C are low, in which case the corresponding diode is forward biased, highly conductive, and "pulling down" the potential at F. That's the behaviour of an AND gate.

You can create any logical gate function using only what I've shown above, by performing boolean manipulations of your desired function to be in terms of NOT, AND and OR. For example, NOR:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBGAhB.png)</sup>

Your question about how to make an AND gate is already answered, then, using just diodes, but it doesn't amplify, and there's still a diode-junction "loss" of 0.6V which may be problematic for subsequent stages.

One of the coolest things you can do with common-emitter configurations is combine several, and connect all the collectors together:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOjdfs.png)</sup>

On the left, any "on" transistor (base high) pulls F low, which is a NOR function. To the right, by using PNP transistors we have a similar condition in which any "on" device (base low) will take the output F high, for NAND behaviour.

This arrangement is used very often with "open-collector" outputs. Check out the [LM393](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/lm393-d.pdf) comparator, and the [74HC03](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hct03.pdf) logic IC. These have open-collector or open-drain outputs that can be wired together in this way (a technique called "wire-OR" or "wire-AND") to combine outputs from multiple devices without the need for additional logic gates.

By inverting the output from the right hand circuit, we have AND, which yields my second suggested solution to your problem:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBxLSC.png)</sup>

Finally, if you insist on using NPN transistors to perform AND, one way is to invert the inputs, and then NOR them:

$$ A \cdot B = \overline{\overline{A} + \overline{B}} $$

This is my third solution to your problem:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fobfl8.png)</sup>

A couple of points about this last design. The nodes A' and B' do not ever rise above +0.7V, since they are clamped to this maximum by the base-emitter junctions of Q3 and Q4. The reason I can get away with so few resistors in this design is due to the fact that R3 and R4 form not only part of the inverters, but also serve as current-limiting base resistors for Q3 and Q4. This is what I alluded to earlier - whether you choose PNP or NPN devices depends on what comes next, and what comes before. In this case I got lucky, and was able to fulfill two goals with a single resistor.

Lastly I want to warn you about confusing an LED being on (a load passing current) and a logical "high":

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBPKzq.png)</sup>

Here I demonstrate that the LED will be lit when the output is low, not high! That's somewhat counter-intuitive, and a big source of confusion. In all my examples above I have treated high and low potentials and corresponding to logic 1 and 0 respectively, and if you build any of those circuits with LEDs to indicate logic state, beware this potential gotcha!

---

#### Update

To address you comment, and clarify the follower behaviour of your Q2, consider this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwK77U.png)</sup>

On the left is a normal emitter follower. The base is held at +5V, and this places the emitter 0.7V below that, at +4.3V. Due to the "load" R1 at the emitter, by Ohm's law we can say that the current through R1 is 430μA.

Pay attention to where that "emitter current" is coming from. If the collector is connected to +5V, almost all the current comes in via that route, and the base only contributes only a tiny amount in comparison. The transistor is operating as you would expect, as a current amplifier, in which the source of +5V at the base is required to supply very little current, and the transistor takes care of the rest, drawing current from whatever supply is connected to the collector.

What happens, though, if you don't connect a power source to the collector? That's exemplified in the middle circuit. At first it doesn't seem that much changes, since the emitter is still at +4.3V, the same as before, and the current through the load is 430μA, also the same as before. The difference is where that current comes from. With no power supply at the collector to source any current from, it's the source at the base which has to do all the work. All 430μA comes in via the base instead.

The reason for the emitter rising to +4.3V in this case is the base-emittter junction, which behaves like any P-N junction (AKA diode) behaves. When forward biased (as it is in the middle circuit), it develops 0.7V across it, and conducts heavily.

To illustrate this, I've reproduced the same conditions on the right, using just a diode instead of the transistor. From the perspective of load R3, conditions are identical. The center and right-hand circuits above are electrically equivalent.

Focusing on the left and middle circuits, the only difference is the presence/absence of a connection to +5V at the collector. If you imagine that this connection/disconnection is under control of another transistor (Q1 in your original circuit), its state (on or off) cannot possibly have any effect on the potential across our load. All it can change is the *route* via which those 430μA are sourced, but the load will still have 4.3V across it, regardless.

That "diode" between Q1's base and emitter makes it impossible to use two or more bipolar transistors, as you've configured them, to behave like on/off switches in series, as you had hoped.

Comment: Thanks. I've got a few more comments if you don't mind. I'm not following completely on the follower part (no pun intended) and why the voltage should be high. In my understanding the voltage is of importance to the MOSFET gate, but the BJT's base only cares about current, so I can't quite make sense of that.

Comment: Continued: The way I've thought of digital logic is that there's either current, or there isn't. So a little is the same as a lot (both true), so if it's enough to power an LED, it's on (I'm aware of the gotcha in your last example, it's because the LED is connected in the wrong place, it should be between the collector and its own ground). I have some NPN transistors and a few PNP to experiment with, but they look exactly the same (so I prefer to only use one type to avoid confusion). Do you have any advice how to deal with that?

Comment: @QwertYuiop I've added another section to my answer, to (hopefully) address your confusion about the emitter followers. As for your statement about digital logic being about "current or no current", I disagree very strongly. It's always been about "voltage or no voltage", from ancient RTL, DTL and TTL systems to modern CMOS ones.

Comment: @QwertYuiop Perhaps your confusion stems from the common description of the BJT as a "current amplifier". This is true, but I feel that it's misleading, because BJTs also amplify voltage. Current and voltage are just different manifest properties of the same underlying phenomenon, electricity, and which description you use is purely a matter of context. The biggest issue you face in your own circuit has to do with the base-emitter junction being a diode, whose consequences are numerous, including limiting \$V_{BE}\$ to 0.7V maximum.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean " current or no current" in general, but in the context of BJT, since the emitter current is directly related to the base current (either one to one if the collector is disconnected, or amplifying if the collector can provide sufficient current).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there's no path for the base current to flow through Q1 and Q2 to turn them on and hence turn on Q3.

A simple modification should sort that:

[image]

Comment: I don't see a change in your schematic.

Comment: @TypeIA That's because the OP has edited the schematic in the question. You'll have to view the edit history to see it.

Comment: I did that. Aside from reorienting some components I still don't see the change. What am I missing?

Comment: @TypeIA ground connection added to battery negative

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for "light up the Led when both buttons are pressed" the circuit below should work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8P147.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You basically made an AND by making a NOR with a NOT on both inputs. What I don't like about this is that now it wastes power when the LED is off, through the 470 ohm resistor. Also I just happen to use buttons, but they could just as well be signals coming from another device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a relative beginner, but the main reason is because the link you gave uses a simplified transistor model (it's generally a great resource though!), treating it as either a closed or open circuit. Even if it takes into account the base-emitter current, the output is not pulled to the full +6V and is thus considered "off". In your circuit, I suspect the same is happening -- the small base-emitter current may be enough to turn the LED on, but not enough to be considered "high" at the output.

Michal's circuit uses only 1 transistor to accomplish your goal, because the "AND"ing is done through the switches. Some more examples of transistor-less logic gates can be found [here](https://circuitfever.com/logic-gates-using-diodes-and-transistor). Using [CMOS design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMOS), a NAND gate uses 4 transistors and an inverter uses 2, for a total of 6 transistors to build an AND gate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be leakage current.  If so, the solution is to add two resistors to your circuit.

Add one 10 K resistor from the base of Q1 to GND.  Add another 10 K resistor from the base of Q2 to GND.

These resistors do for Q1 and Q2 what R5 does for Q3 - assure a fast and *complete* turn-off of the transistors when their bases are floating.

Side notes:  Because Q3 is operating as an emitter follower, you can eliminate R3.  Also, R5 can be a 10 K just like the others.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
You can make AND gate with two NPN transistors. Please find attached the diagram.

Ref: https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/designing-and-gate-using-transistors

Comment: This is exactly the one from (http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Electronic/trangate.html) that in the original post I pointed out doesn't work. The issue is that you'll still get current at the output if only input B is on, as the base current freely goes through to the emitter.